# Show two bar plots with geom points and single legend using subplots in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to show two bar plots with geom points on it using subplots.
my code -

```
df_1 <- iris[,c("Species", "Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
df_2 <- iris[,c("Species", "Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")]
df_1["Condition_1"] <- "P condition"
df_1[10:20,"Condition_1"] <- "Q condition"
df_1[20:30,"Condition_1"] <- "R condition"
df_1[30:40,"Condition_1"] <- "S condition"
df_1[40:50,"Condition_1"] <- "T condition"

df_1[60:70,"Condition_1"] <- "Q condition"
df_1[70:80,"Condition_1"] <- "R condition"
df_1[80:90,"Condition_1"] <- "S condition"
df_1[90:100,"Condition_1"] <- "T condition"

df_1[110:120,"Condition_1"] <- "Q condition"
df_1[120:130,"Condition_1"] <- "R condition"
df_1[130:140,"Condition_1"] <- "S condition"
df_1[140:150,"Condition_1"] <- "T condition"


df_2["Condition_2"] <- "P condition"
df_2[10:20,"Condition_2"] <- "Q condition"
df_2[20:30,"Condition_2"] <- "R condition"
df_2[30:40,"Condition_2"] <- "S condition"
df_2[40:50,"Condition_2"] <- "T condition"

df_2[60:70,"Condition_2"] <- "Q condition"
df_2[70:80,"Condition_2"] <- "R condition"
df_2[80:90,"Condition_2"] <- "S condition"
df_2[90:100,"Condition_2"] <- "T condition"

df_2[110:120,"Condition_2"] <- "Q condition"
df_2[120:130,"Condition_2"] <- "R condition"
df_2[130:140,"Condition_2"] <- "S condition"
df_2[140:150,"Condition_2"] <- "T condition"
Condition_1 <- as.vector(unique(df_1$Condition))
Species_1 <- unique(df_1$Species)
mean_df_delta <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0)), c("Species", "Condition", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))
for(Species_name in Species_1){
  mean_df_1 <- aggregate(.~Condition_1,data=df_1,function(x) c(M = mean(x)))
  mean_df_1["Species"] <- Species_name
  num <- assign(paste("sam_df", as.character(Species_name), sep = "_"), mean_df_1)
  mean_df_delta <- rbind(mean_df_delta,num)
}
mean_df_normalized <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0)), c("Species", "Condition", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))
Species_2 <- unique(df_2$Species)
Condition_2 <- as.vector(unique(df_2$Condition))
for(Species_name in Species_2){
  mean_df_2 <- aggregate(.~Condition_2,data=df_2,function(x) c(M = mean(x)))
  mean_df_2["Species"] <- Species_name
  num <- assign(paste("sam_df", as.character(Species_name), sep = "_"), mean_df_2)
  mean_df_normalized <- rbind(mean_df_normalized,num)
}

delta_ct_plot <- ggplotly(ggplot(mean_df_delta, aes(fill=Condition_1, y=Petal.Length, x=Species)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") +
                    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Petal.Length+Petal.Width, ymin=Petal.Length-Petal.Width) , position=position_dodge(width=0.9), width=0.25) +
                    geom_point(data=df_1,
                               aes(Species,Petal.Length,color=Condition_1),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
                               colour = "black")+theme(legend.title=element_blank()))
normalized_bar_plot <- ggplotly(ggplot(mean_df_normalized, aes(fill=Condition_2, y=Sepal.Length, x=Species)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") +
                            geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, ymin=Sepal.Length-Sepal.Width) , position=position_dodge(width=0.9), width=0.25) +
                            geom_point(data=df_2,
                                       aes(Species,Sepal.Length,color=Condition_2),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
                                       colour = "black")+theme(legend.title=element_blank()))
subplot(delta_ct_plot, normalized_bar_plot)
```

Now `mean_df_delta` and `mean_df_normalized` is my dataframe for bar plots and error bar. `df_1` and `df_2` is dataframe for geom points.

[image: result i am getting]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ECY.png)

Now in above image legends are getting repeated. I only want legend 1 time.
And I want that all the geom points are of colour black. Bar color should not get fill in geom point.

I had already seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389576/plotly-subplot-with-two-ggplots-and-common-legend). But this is not applied in my case as I have different dataframes for bar and geom points.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(exp_files_con)` into your question? Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to learn how to create reproducible examples in R.

Comment: In `aes()` use `aes(show.legend = FALSE)`

Comment: @anup already tried that.Also tried other likes hidelegend(), guides(fill=FALSE), scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE), theme(legend.position="none").Only hidelegend() and theme(legend.position="none") work and it removes all the legend if i put these in second plot. i.e. in second argument of subplot

Comment: @hpesoj626 it is dataframe with 4 column Condition,Value,Gene,Sd_Error and there respective value

Comment: @prateekeshwarsingh, again, please read through this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. We cannot help you if we can't reproduce your problem. We can only reproduce your problem if you provide us your data set. The easiest way to do that is to paste the output of `dput(exp_files_con)` into your question.

Comment: @hpesoj626 now written whole code with generalised dataframe "iris".You can just copy and run this code.Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `ggplotly` is rendering each of the group labels from each of the subplots. Use `facet_wrap()` instead to generate only 1 set of labels. To do this, I have changed the loops you did into an entirely "tidy" approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
df <- iris

df["Condition"] <- "P condition"
df[10:20,"Condition"] <- "Q condition"
df[20:30,"Condition"] <- "R condition"
df[30:40,"Condition"] <- "S condition"
df[40:50,"Condition"] <- "T condition"

df[60:70,"Condition"] <- "Q condition"
df[70:80,"Condition"] <- "R condition"
df[80:90,"Condition"] <- "S condition"
df[90:100,"Condition"] <- "T condition"

df[110:120,"Condition"] <- "Q condition"
df[120:130,"Condition"] <- "R condition"
df[130:140,"Condition"] <- "S condition"
df[140:150,"Condition"] <- "T condition"

df1 <- df %>%
  gather(var, value, -Condition, -Species) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  separate(var, into = c("var", "measure")) %>%
  group_by(measure) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  spread(measure, value) %>%
  select(-id)


df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Length:Width), mean) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ymax = Length + Width,
         ymin = Length - Width) %>%
  unique()



p <- df2 %>% ggplot(aes(fill=Condition, y=Length, x=Species)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin) , position=position_dodge(width=0.9), width=0.25) +
  geom_point(data=df1,
             aes(Species,Length,color=Condition),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
             colour = "black")+theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + 
  facet_wrap(~var, scales = "free_y") + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

I also have to note that averaging by Condition only doesn't make sense to me. But I think you just have to adjust to your use case.

Comment: is it possible to fill all the geom points with black color.The bar color should not get fill in geom point.

Comment: I am afraid I am not that familiar with `ggplotly`. Try posting that as a question and you might get an answer.

Comment: used above code directly.But it is showing plot for only sepal.Petal plot is not shown it is coming empty.